# PostgreSQL knex failing to connect to port "Unhandled rejection Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have been trying to setup postgres for Node using knex and am thoroughly confused.

I've got knex set-up with postgres as follows:

```
//db.js
const config = require('../knexfile.js');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const knex = require("knex")(config[env]);

module.exports = knex;

knex.migrate.latest([config]);


//knexfile.js
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'devUser',
        password: 'dbpassword',
        port: 5432,
        database: 'example-name'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds/development'
    }
 },
  production: ....
}
```

Then when I try and run Node...

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get('port')}/`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
});

module.exports = app;
```

...I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I've seen this message when you try and run two processes on the same port, but running `netstat -p tcp | grep 5432` returns nothing. Can you see what I've missed?

Comment: Well...if nothing is running on port 5432, wouldn't that explain why you can't connect to a postgres database running on port 5432?

Comment: Ah OK - feel stupid now. I was confused because when I had the database up I was getting a 'Migration Lock' error, so I thought maybe Node kicked up the postgres server. I've shifted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039269/mocha-testing-postgresql-with-knex-is-giving-me-a-migrationlocked-error